# MySQL - juntar resultados de diversas colunas

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela MySQL onde preciso em um só resultado campos que estejam em 3 colunas diferentes. Vou dar um exemplo:

```
Col.A         Col.B       Col.C
Joaquim       Sérgio      Ricardo
Ricardo       Maria       César
Rafael        Solange     Joaquim
```

O resultado precisa vir:

```
Joaquim, Sérgio, Ricardo, Maria, César, Rafael, Solange
```

Ou seja, ele busca o resultado em 3 colunas e me retorna em um só array.

Obrigado pela força...

Answer (score 2):

> A query abaixo vai retornar exatamente como você pediu: Joaquim, Sérgio, Ricardo, Maria, César, Rafael, Solange

```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT colA FROM SuaTabela UNION SELECT DISTINCT colB FROM SuaTabela UNION SELECT DISTINCT colC FROM SuaTabela");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $nome=$row['colA'];
        $array=$array.$nome.",";
    }
    //retira a última virgula do array
    $array = substr($array,0,-1);
```

> **Considerações**

1. A extensão MySQL está descontinuado, portanto o mais ideal é você utilizar mysqli ou PDO.
2. Como já conhecemos, a forma padrão para declarar arrays em PHP é a seguinte:

   **$nomes = array('joaquim', 'Ricardo', 'Rafael');**

   A partir do PHP5.4, temos uma nova forma de declarar arrays

   **$nomes = ['joaquim', 'Ricardo', 'Rafael'];**

Não obstante a sua pergunta dá margem a várias interpretações quanto ao nome da tabela e das colunas.
   Dependendo dos nomes as querys podem ser:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT col.A FROM col UNION SELECT DISTINCT col.B FROM col UNION SELECT DISTINCT col.C FROM col
```

ou, que dá no mesmo que a acima

```
 SELECT DISTINCT A FROM col UNION SELECT DISTINCT B FROM col UNION SELECT DISTINCT C FROM col
```

> Por fim se o nome das suas colunas possuem mesmo ponto nos nomes então os nomes das colunas na query devem ficar entre aspas invertidas:

```
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `col.A` FROM stabela UNION SELECT DISTINCT `col.B` FROM stabela UNION SELECT DISTINCT `col.C` FROM stabela");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $nome=$row['col.A'];
        $array=$array.$nome.",";
    }
    $array = substr($array,0,-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Somente utilizando MySQL!**

Você pode usar o [`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) para pegar todas as colunas separadas por virgula desa forma  resultará em:

```
Joaquim, Sérgio, Ricardo
Ricardo, Maria, César
Rafael, Solange, Joaquim
```

Depois utiliza o [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) para juntar todos numa só linha, assim:

```
Joaquim, Sérgio, Ricardo, Ricardo, Maria, César, Rafael, Solange, Joaquim
```

---

No final terá isto:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
       CONCAT_WS(',', `Col.A`, `Col.B`, `Col.C`)) 
FROM tabela
```

Pronto, isto fará todo o trabalho sem o PHP. Entretanto, você deve notar a configuração do `group_concat_max_len` em seu `my.cnf`, você pode ver também utilizando (`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%group_concat_max_len%'`) e se o `GROUP_CONCAT` usar for muito longo será limitado por essa configuração.

---

Answer (score 0):

o uso da função CONCAT_WS() no meu ponto de vista é muito melhor,e nativo!

Não ha necessidade de usar a aplicação neste caso, a não ser que seja algo interino.